# selecting option in a <select> using JQuery

Tags: jquery

How do you use JQuery to make an option in a  object selected?  Here is my  :

```
    <select id='ddlMeter'>
<option value='#ff3333' style='background-color:#ff3333; color:#ff3333'>red</option>
<option value='#ffee44' style='background-color:#ffee44; color:#ffee44'>amber</option>
<option value='#33ee66' style='background-color:#33ee66; color:#33ee66'>green</option>
<option value='#333333' style='background-color:#333333; color:#333333'>black</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the `Attribute` **selected**. You can do this by invoking [`.attr()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Example:

```
$('select option:eq(1)').attr('selected', true);
```

will select the second option. As an alternative, you may set the [`.val()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on the parent `<option>` element.

```
$('select').val('#ffee44');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#ddlMeter").val("#33ee66");
```

Answer (score 1):

To mark an option selected, you can just set the `val()` of the select item.

```
$('#ddlMeter').val('#333333');  //black is selected
```